# How to make a contained control in a view to do operation by ViewModel triger?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I have a view that containing a user control.
I want to make the view model to notify the user control to do some action (refresh its' data).

I can pace some bool property in my VM and bind it to the user control so it will trigger it, but I think it's a little abuse of the property.

I feel I missing something, and can't find a solution. I will appreciate any comment.

My solution:
I'm going to solve the problem by registering an event of collection changed in my UserControl, since I'm binding to that control a view of a collection thru CollectionViewSource. 
My original problem was how to make a chart control inside the UserControl to get updated when I filtering the data source. After the filtering operation from the VM, an event will raise and I will make the chart to get refresh either in the UserContol's code behind

Comment: If you have bound to a VM properly you normally don't need your UserControl to refresh() as its underlying Changes should be propagated to the view via the INotifyProperyChanged Interface

Comment: I know that. But the user control contain more things that need maintenance

Answer (score 1):

Since you've indicated MVVM tag solution would be pretty straightforward - just bind control to a data by exposing data items/whatever by ViewModel so any data updates would be automatically dispatched to View via bndings if you would provide `INotifyPropertyChanged` / `INotifyCollectionChanged` by a ViewModel.

Comment: I'm using MVVM, but inside the user control, I need to do some operation, that need to be triggered from the VM.

Answer (score 1):

If you've bound your UserControl correctly, you shouldn't need to manually refresh the data since WPF will automatically update the UI when `INotifiyPropertyChanged` triggers

That said, if you wish to send a message from the ViewModel to the View, I usually use an messaging system of some kind to keep the Views and ViewModels separate. The two I've used and would recommend are [MVVM Light's Messenger](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/), or [Microsoft Prism's EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)

Either system will allow your ViewModel to broadcast a message, and your View can subscribe to receive these messages and handle them as needed.

Comment: Thank you for the idea of messaging.